# Blendshapes in Unity vs Blender

Tags: unity, blender, mesh, fbx

I have a model from a package that has existing Blendshapes that work fine.  I'm a bit of a Blender newb, though. I'm trying to add a Blendshape for spikiness to a cube model.  It's early WIP, but it looks roughly the way I expect it to in Blender.  However, when exported and imported into Unity, the mesh with the blendshape applied isn't quite right - the spikes are sort of... plump, as if it isn't quite changing the vertices the same way.  Is there anything specific that needs to be done with this process?  Am I missing something, or is there some tuning I need to do in Blender prior to exporting the FBX?

Blender: http://www.labyrintheer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/spike_bs_blender.mp4

Unity: http://www.labyrintheer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/spike_bs_unity.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I was able to answer my own issue. The root cause had to do with Blender using quads as opposed to tris.  The way I morphed the mesh for the blendshape did not allow for very good quad->tri conversion.  I modified the way I managed the blendshape (moved all 8 surrounding vertices in toward the pulled vertex), and the spikes now look... like spikes.

If anyone comes to this because they have a similar issue - consider how your quads are going to convert to tris.  If a single quad in Blender is stretched AND curved (it can happen in modeling) it will not become good tris as a single quad is *always* broken into exactly two tris.

In the following example, the face we're looking at, my initial attempt was like the right spike, and the resolved attempt was the left spike.
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the right spike creates two "shapes" of quads at the deformation.  The larger quads (two on top, two on the bottom, two on each side) aren't really a huge issue, however the quads that make up each "quadrant" of the spike are problematic geometry.  This image highlights their somewhat boomerang shape:

[image]

Given that there's no edge where the spike juts out, it's plausible that the FBX could be imported and have good tris that split there, but that's sort of a wish and a prayer.

Pulling in all eight surrounding vertices changes the breakdown of the geometry considerably.  Here's another close-up:
[image]

Your mileage may vary, but as a game developer, I tend to think in tris and didn't really consider just how differently quads work, especially when they're parsed into tris at import.

Comment: Good catch. Some screenshots or diagrams to show the triangulation issue or how you solved it could make this answer even more informative for future readers.

Comment: @DMGregory - good call, I'll do that.